# Yet another "inconsistent mappings", "owning side field does not exist" Doctrine issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I encountered a "mappings X and Y are inconsistent with each other" Doctrine error, so 
I starting by browsing a little bit similar questions here on SE :

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254110/the-mappings-are-inconsistent-with-each-other) makes the 
mistake of using the same `mappedby` key several times - not my case.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869086/doctrine-issue-mappings-inconsistent)
makes the mistake of connecting entities to one another by ID's rather than object references. As I do not
specify the types (see below) that does not seem to be my problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417318/the-mappings-entity-and-entity-are-inconsistent-with-each-other-symfony2-d) uses yml files to specify mappings - not my case.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926916/mappings-are-inconsistent-with-each-other-single-table-inheritance)
incorrectly names the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` keys - not my case as far as I can see.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926916/mappings-are-inconsistent-with-each-other-single-table-inheritance)
is solved by using FQCN inside the annotations, which I did - see below.

The complete error message :

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\Comment' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings AppBundle\Entity\Comment#cmtauthor and AppBundle\Entity\User#comments are inconsistent with each other.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\User' mapping is invalid:
* The association AppBundle\Entity\User#comments refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\Comment#cmtauthour which does not exist.

[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
$
```

And here are the contents of my classes (for simplicity I don't include
the getters/setters/constructors automatically generated by Doctrine ) :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validation\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="nruser")
*
**/

class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment",
     *      mappedBy="cmtauthour",
     *      orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     * 
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post",
     *      mappedBy="postauthor",
     *      orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     * 
     */
    private $posts;



}

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="post")
*
**/

class Post
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment",
     *      mappedBy="post",
     *      orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     * 
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $postauthor;



}

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="comment")
*
**/

class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $cmtauthor;




}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's just a typo in your User::comments mapping. Change it to `mappedBy="cmtauthor"`

Comment: @hasumedic Indeed, solves the first problem. Thanks

Comment: The second problem is not possible to solve from here because we don't know the state of your DB. But basically, what you describe in your mapping is not what you have in your current DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check why `schema is not in sync` dump schema update queries:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Comment: Indeed. That allowed me to solve the problem, thanks (in fact I read about this idea elsewhere and used it before reading your answer)